# Jagged Array Dimensions

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I'm using jagged arrays and have a bit of a problem (or at least I think I do).  The size of these arrays are determined by how many rows are returned in a database, so it is very variable. The only solution I have is to set the dimensions of the array to be very huge, but this seems ... just not the best way to do things.

```
int[][] hulkSmash = new int[10][];
hulkSmash[0] = new int[2] {1,2};
```

How can I work with jagged arrays without setting the dimensions, or is this just a fact of life with C# programming??

Comment: Why not just use a List<List<int>> or something that has mutability built in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<List<int>> hulkSmash = new List<List<int>>();
hulkSmash.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
```

or

```
List<int[]> hulkSmash = new List<int[]>();
hulkSmash.Add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
```

Comment: Since I've never worked with a list before, which is the preferred method?  A list of lists or a list or arrays?

Comment: If you know how big the inner lists are and they will never need to be modified then an array is lighter and there is really no 'need' for it to be a list. If there is ANY chance that you will need to modify it or wont know the initial size then a list would be preferred.

Comment: A list uses an array internally. It just handles all of the resizing, etc., for you.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 choices:

- You can read the size of the information returned from the database, and allocate your array space at that time, once you know what you're getting.
- Otherwise, what you're looking for is a data structure that has variable dimensions. Take a look at List for example: [MSDN: List< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The other examples using `List<T>` and collections are the best way to proceed. I sometimes find the

```
List<List<int>> hulkSmash = new List<List<int>>();
```

syntax a tad unwieldy. Luckily, there are some options to manage this.

The first option I sometimes use is to make an alias:

```
using List<List<int>> = HulkSmashCollection;
```

This prevents you from having to do nested `<<<Types>>>` all the time. Everywhere you'd type `List<List<int>>` you can instead type `HulkSmashCollection` (or something shorter still) instead.

---

The second option is to wrap the List of Lists within a class called, say, MyHulkSmashes. Here, you only provide the functions/properties you need, like `Count` or `Find()` etc.

Both these concepts are used to reduce the amount of code on screen, and reduce perceived complexity.

Comment: ...or even declare a `public class HulkSmashCollection: List<List<int>> {}`

Comment: Best way to go through a list?  Loop through using foreach?

Comment: Yes, although there are caveats. The collection may not change during iteration. Thus, adding or removing items from a list (or any IEnumerable collection, for that matter) will throw an exception.

Comment: Although not recommended, you can alter items in a list by looping backwards through it...

Answer (score 0):

A collection of ints (such as List) will give you the flexibility that you want and not waste space as would allocating an array that is much larger than you will ever need.